# Windows <sys/file.h> equivalent

Tags: linux, winapi, port, header-files

Is there a Win32 equivalent to the linux  header file?  I'm working on a Linux to Windows port (and my first time doing so) and it's failing on this file.

Comment: MinGW does provide a <sys/file.h>, though it essentially just points back to <fcntl.h>...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing WIN32API apps you usually `#include <windows.h>` - that includes most of the Windows API in your application. If you need to cut down on some of those includes, `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` will wipe out some of the more obscure things from the Windows libraries.

What functions are you trying to convert? It'll probably be a case of using a different function on WIN32; it is very different to Linux/Unix/POSIX.

Example: the [`ReadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28VS.85%29.aspx) function is roughly equivalent to [`read()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/read.html) in terms of general idea, but the calling signatures are very different. ReadFile()'s MSDN entry says:

> Header: WinBase.h (include Windows.h)

Answer (score 2):

If you are porting to windows, it would be far easier to stick to cross platform standards, than diving straight into a native windows API port (CreateFile etc.).

I don't know what functionality is in `<sys/file.h>`, it looks like its part of the POSIX standard header files, but I can't find a reference to it in the posix sources.

There are a few build environments that you can use to port posix applications to Windows.

- If your application sticks to the C standard library for things like file IO, Dev Studio should support most of that natively. `<stdio.h>` for example has things like `fopen`.
- [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) provides a set of tools, but uses the microsoft c-runtime, so things like pthreads should be missing.
- [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is a far more conformant POSIX build environment.
- [SUA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779522(WS.10).aspx) is Microsofts own offering.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of posterity, `<sys/file.h>` is the BSD version of low-level file I/O routines.  Depending upon your compiler installation and build environment, you'll probably want `<fcntl.h>` instead.  Most of the usual I/O routines are in `<stdio.h>`, even `setvbuf()` which is pretty low-level control.  You'll want `<windows.h>` or `<conio.h>` if you want I/O routines/settings that don't normally exist under Linux (or the other *NICES).