# frama-c mingw __restrict__ keyword

Tags: frama-c

I am new to Frama-C. I would like to run it under Windows enviroments. My compiler is gcc,mingw.

I have tryied to run same examples from Value Analysis tutorial by I have a problem with library header files.

I've found that it's not possible to run frama-c because **restrict** keyword. It shows error in string.h file

```
  void * __cdecl memcpy(void * __restrict__ _Dst,const void * __restrict__ _Src,size_t _Size) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
```

When I manually add #define **restrict** to all  *.c files in SkeinProject

```
schneier.com/code/skein_NIST_CD_102610.zip
```

everything works correcly. By doing it by hand is not what I'm looking for.

Next step was to add argument -D__restrict__

```
frama-c -cpp-extra-args=-D__restrict__ -main=Init -val SHA3api_ref.c

[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I. -D__restrict__ SHA3api_ref.c"
../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:41:[kernel] user error: syntax error
[kernel] user error: skipping file "SHA3api_ref.c" that has errors.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted because of an invalid user input.
```

I've also generated precompiled *.i files but error still the same.

```
gcc -E -D__restrict__ SHA3api_ref.c >SHA3api_ref.i

frama-c -main=Init -val SHA3api_ref.i

../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:41:[kernel] user error: syntax error
[kernel] user error: skipping file "SHA3api_ref.i" that has errors.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted because of an invalid user input.
```

What can I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system headers contain non-standard syntax extensions that are not supported by Frama-C. This is normal, as the headers are often provided as part of a complete package with the compiler, so the headers and the compiler only need to work together, not to work with all the other programs that take C source code as input.

Generally speaking, you should always use the headers provided with Frama-C
instead of those from your system.

When using GCC or a compatible compiler such as Clang, this involves
passing the pre-processor the options `-nostdinc` and `-I...` where `...`
stands for the place where Frama-C's headers were installed. This
location can be obtained from Frama-C with the option `-print-share-path`.

All in all, on a Unix system, it may look like:

```
frama-c -cpp-extra-args=-nostdinc -cpp-extra-args=-I`frama-c -print-share-path`/libc .....
```

Doing the same thing with Windows and MinGW follows the same idea but sometimes involves extra trouble due to the perpetual ambiguity between `\` and `/` as directory separators.

Recently, Frank Dordowsky has been having trouble with using a very new GCC version to pre-process C files for Frama-C. That was only when using `-pp-annot`, but in any case, the solution was to switch to Clang as pre-processor.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now :) 
I have used gcc -E -nostdinc -IC:\Frama-C\share\frama-c\libc  *.c >project.i to preprocess project first and then 
frama-c -val -slevel=100 project.i
Btw using frama-c -cpp-extra-args=-nostdinc -cpp-extra-args=-IC:\Frama-C\share\frama-c\libc.....  was not working for me, but it doesn't matter now.

Comment: frama-c -cpp-extra-args=-nostdinc -cpp-extra-args=-IC:\Frama-C\share\frama-c\libc -val *.c

[kernel] user error: failed to run: gcc -C -E -I. -nostdinc -IC:\Frama-C\share\frama-c\libc -o "C:\DOCUME~1\User\Temp\main.c703d6d.i" "main.c"
you may set the CPP environment variable to select the prop
er preprocessor command or use the option "-cpp-command".
[kernel] user error: skipping file "main.c" that has errors.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted because of an invalid user input.